# Split string and extract between two characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string in excel that looks like this:

```
String1 = "L100;G50;XYZ12,5;E11/11/2018;NF1;Osomefreetext"
```

I want to extract parts of this string and save them as variables:

```
var1 = 100 (part of the string between "L" and next ";"
var2 = 50 (part of the string between "G" and next ";"
var3 = 12 (part of the string between "XYZ" and next ";"
var4 = 11/11/2018 (part of the string between "E" and next";"
var5 = 1 (part of the string between "NF" and next ";"
var6 = somefreetext (part of the string between "O" and next ";"
```

I know the VBA Split function, which would split my string based on the delimiter of choice (in my case ";")

```
Split(String1, ";")
```

However the order of the different substrings is not constant, meaning for example that the "G"part can come before the "L" part, or the "XYZ"part can be at the end.

So how can I extract different substrings based on the beginning pattern, but still taking into account the ";" delimiter.

Comment: `split` coupled with `select case`? It seems like a straightforward programming job to loop over the result of `split`.

Comment: Or a regex that only parses the parts you want.

Comment: There is no finishing `;` in your sample. Is that a mistype or can the text string to be processed lack a trailing semi-colon?

Comment: @user10735198: there is indeed no ";" at the end.

Comment: A trailing semi colon can be added I believe. I would do that for simplicity of the code.

Comment: Is the string always in lowercase?

Comment: How about using Mid() in combination with the Instr() function to determine the position of e.g. 'G'?
Something like var1 = Mid(Value, Instr(Value, "G")+1, Instr(Instr(Value, "G")+1,Value,";")-Instr(Value, "G")+1) out the top of my head

Comment: @Andreas combination of lowercase and uppercase

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach, using the `Like` operator:

```
Sub test()
    Dim var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6 'as variant
    Dim string1 As String, s As String
    Dim items As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    string1 = "L100;G50;XYZ12,5;E11/11/2018;NF1;Osomefreetext"
    items = Split(string1, ";")

    For i = 0 To UBound(items)
        s = items(i)
        If s Like "L*" Then
            var1 = Mid(s, 2)
        ElseIf s Like "G*" Then
            var2 = Mid(s, 2)
        ElseIf s Like "XYZ*" Then
            var3 = Mid(s, 4)
        ElseIf s Like "E*" Then
            var4 = Mid(s, 2)
        ElseIf s Like "NF*" Then
            var5 = Mid(s, 3)
        ElseIf s Like "O*" Then
            var6 = Mid(s, 2)
        'Else error trapping code
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Extracted " & Join(Array(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6), ", ")

End Sub
```

Output:

```
Extracted 100, 50, 12,5, 11/11/2018, 1, somefreetext
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim String1 As String, s As String
    Dim vR(), vS
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    String1 = "L100;G50;XYZ12,5;E11/11/2018;NF1;Osomefreetext"

    vS = Split(String1, ";")
    ReDim vR(UBound(vS))
    For i = 0 To UBound(vS) - 1
        s = Split(vS(i), ",")(0)
        For j = 1 To Len(s)
            If Mid(s, j, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
               s = Replace(s, Mid(s, j, 1), "")
               j = j - 1
            End If
        Next j
        vR(i) = s
    Next i
    s = vS(i)
    vR(i) = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
    Range("a1").Resize(1, i + 1) = vR
End Sub
```

** Result

vR(0) =100

vR(1)= 50

vR(2)= 12

vR(3)= 11/11/2018

vR(4) = 1

vR(5)= somefreetext

Answer (score 0):

In the VBE, add a new class module (Alt+I, C) and paste in the following.

**[CExtract class module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611994/vba-excel-split-string-and-extract-between-two-characters/53613185#53613185)**

```
Option Explicit

Private pL As Long
Private pG As Long
Private pXYZ As Long
Private pE As Date
Private pNF As Long
Private pO As String

Public Property Get L() As Long
    L = pL
End Property
Public Property Let L(Value As Long)
    pL = Value
End Property

Public Property Get G() As Long
    G = pG
End Property
Public Property Let G(Value As Long)
    pG = Value
End Property

Public Property Get XYZ() As Long
    XYZ = pXYZ
End Property
Public Property Let XYZ(Value As Long)
    pXYZ = Value
End Property

Public Property Get e() As Date
    e = pE
End Property
Public Property Let e(Value As Date)
    pE = Value
End Property

Public Property Get NF() As Long
    NF = pNF
End Property
Public Property Let NF(Value As Long)
    pNF = Value
End Property

Public Property Get O() As String
    O = pO
End Property
Public Property Let O(Value As String)
    pO = Value
End Property
```

Using the Properties window (Alt+V, W), rename the class to CExtract.

[image]

Populate and use the new class like this.

**[Module1 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611994/vba-excel-split-string-and-extract-between-two-characters/53613185#53613185)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim extract As New CExtract, string1 As String

    string1 = "L100;G50;XYZ12,5;E11/11/2018;NF1;Osomefreetext"

    buildExtract extract, string1

    Debug.Print extract.e
    Debug.Print extract.G
    Debug.Print extract.L
    Debug.Print extract.NF
    Debug.Print extract.O
    Debug.Print extract.XYZ

End Sub

Sub buildExtract(ByRef ext As CExtract, str As String)

    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant

    arr = Split(str, Chr(59))

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Select Case Asc(arr(i))
            Case 69 'E
                ext.e = CDate(Mid(arr(i), 2))
            Case 71 'G
                ext.G = CLng(Mid(arr(i), 2))
            Case 76 'L
                ext.L = CLng(Mid(arr(i), 2))
            Case 78 'NF
                ext.NF = CLng(Mid(arr(i), 3))
            Case 79 'O
                ext.O = Mid(arr(i), 2)
            Case 88 'XYZ
                ext.XYZ = CLng(Mid(arr(i), 4))
            Case Else
                Debug.Print "rogue element:" & arr(i)
        End Select
    Next i


End Sub
```

**[Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611994/vba-excel-split-string-and-extract-between-two-characters/53613185#53613185)**

[image]